# Уместно ли слово?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Уместно ли использовано слово «присутствие»: "присутствие столь существенных отличий, уяснение которых требует достаточно основательной подготовки, порождает вопрос о том..."?

Answer (score 1):

Для меня слово *присутствие* обозначает присутствие кого-нибудь, в другом случае я бы предпочла слово *наличие*. Но у Вас тогда получится "наличие отличий", что нехорошо. Другого предложить пока не могу, хотелось бы более широкий контекст.

Answer (score 1):

***"Столь существенные отличия, уяснение которых требует достаточно основательной подготовки, заставляют задуматься о том..."*** Разве что так. В Вашем предложении и "порождает" как-то неуместно, и "присутствие".